# Django template question?

Tags: django

I need to display all the videos within a certain playlist. I can display all the avaliable playlists by using this loop:

```
{% for p in playlists %}

    {{ p.playlist.name }}

{% endfor %}
```

How can I display all the videos in each playlist too?

Comment: How are we supposed to know how to get to the videos in the playlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say since you don't show your models, but something like this could work:

```
<ul>
{% for p in playlists %}

<li>{{ p.playlist.name }}
    <ul>
    {% for v in p.playlist.videos %}
    <li>{{ v.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I'm assuming your videos have a `ForeignKey(Playlist, related_name="videos")` field.

Comment: yeah that's the thing. I would have tried something like what you posted too but I can't find anything remotely descriptive to videos in the playlist model documentation. Guess I have to talk to the backend dev, thanks